# PowerShell vs. sed with complex arguments

Tags: powershell, sed

I tried the following PowerShell script using sed:

```
[array declarations]

Foreach ($var in $double)
{
    $command = $command + " -e "
    $command = $command + "s/$var/sMOS3double\[$var\]\[index\]/"
}
$command = $command + " mos3load_fun_09052012.c > poZamianie.txt"
**echo $command**
sed $command
```

Unfortunatelly, it returns error:

```
**./Renamer.ps1**

 -e 's/vds/sMOS3double\[vds\]\[index\]/' -e 's/vbs/sMOS3double\[vbs\]\[index\]/' -e 's/vgs/sMOS3double\[vgs\]\[index\]/
' -e 's/vbd/sMOS3double\[vbd\]\[index\]/' -e 's/vgd/sMOS3double\[vgd\]\[index\]/' -e 's/vt/sMOS3double\[vt\]\[index\]/'
 -e 's/EffectiveWidth/sMOS3double\[EffectiveWidth\]\[index\]/' -e 's/EffectiveLength/sMOS3double\[EffectiveLength\]\[in
dex\]/' -e 's/OxideCap/sMOS3double\[OxideCap\]\[index\]/' -e 's/Beta/sMOS3double\[Beta\]\[index\]/' -e 's/cdrain/sMOS3d
ouble\[cdrain\]\[index\]/' -e 's/vdsat/sMOS3double\[vdsat\]\[index\]/' -e 's/von/sMOS3double\[von\]\[index\]/' mos3load
_fun_09052012.c > poZamianie.txt

**sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `-'**
```

I tried hard, using configurations of '', "" or no delimiters at all, with no success.

However, then I copied echoed output from PS console and passed it as argument in console again:

```
**sed** -e s/vds/sMOS3double\[vds\]\[index\]
/ -e s/vbs/sMOS3double\[vbs\]\[index\]/ -e s/vgs/sMOS3double\[vgs\]\[index\]/ -e s/vbd/sMOS3double\[vbd\]\[index\]/ -e s
/vgd/sMOS3double\[vgd\]\[index\]/ -e s/vt/sMOS3double\[vt\]\[index\]/ -e s/EffectiveWidth/sMOS3double\[EffectiveWidth\]\
[index\]/ -e s/EffectiveLength/sMOS3double\[EffectiveLength\]\[index\]/ -e s/OxideCap/sMOS3double\[OxideCap\]\[inde\]/ -
e s/Beta/sMOS3double\[Beta\]\[index\]/ -e s/cdrain/sMOS3double\[cdrain\]\[index\]/ -e s/vdsat/sMOS3double\[vdsat\]\[inde
x\]/ -e s/von/sMOS3double\[von\]\[index\]/ mos3load_fun_09052012.c > poZamianie.txt
```

The script executed correctly.

Anybody can explain this behaviour? Or show a way to execute that script directly with PowerShell?

Answer (score 3):

```
invoke-expression "sed $command"
```

It's worked well for me.

Comment: Certainly it worked for me too. Thanks for help. I still wonder why it didn't at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Write this:

```
s/vds/sMOS3double\[vds\]\[index\]/
s/vbs/sMOS3double\[vbs\]\[index\]/
s/vgs/sMOS3double\[vgs\]\[index\]/
s/vbd/sMOS3double\[vbd\]\[index\]/
s/vgd/sMOS3double\[vgd\]\[index\]/
s/vt/sMOS3double\[vt\]\[index\]/
s/EffectiveWidth/sMOS3double\[EffectiveWidth\]\[index\]/
s/EffectiveLength/sMOS3double\[EffectiveLength\]\[index\]/
s/OxideCap/sMOS3double\[OxideCap\]\[index\]/
s/Beta/sMOS3double\[Beta\]\[index\]/
s/cdrain/sMOS3double\[cdrain\]\[index\]/
s/vdsat/sMOS3double\[vdsat\]\[index\]/
```

to a file "meaningful-name.sed", and call it

```
sed -f meaningful-name.sed mos3load_fun_09052012.c > poZamianie.txt
```

In a file of sed-commands, you normally have one command per line, and don't need masking with ' or ".

You even may comments, afaik

```
#
# this style
#
```

with `sed -f commandfile.sed` you invoke it.

Comment: I think the O.P.'s intent using the foreach loop was to dynamically create the sed script to be executed.

Comment: Well, you can write these commands to a tmp.sed file, invoke it, delete it. If you save part of the masking, it is often a simplification.

Comment: yes, forgot to say that I am a big believer in the `sed -f script.sed` pattern, but I got the impression you wanted user to make a permanent file, my fault. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: Well - I wasn't sure whether the command will always change, so I left this open.